# Keyboard shortcuts file gnome

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, gnome

I've recently installed debian gnome alongside kali gnome. I'd setup a lot of keybindings in kali according to my needs. Is there a way I can port them to debian by, like, copying some config file.

Answer (score 4):

Keyboard Mappings are stored in the dconf registry.
`dconf-editor` is a graphical tool to browse the registry.

For a textual representation you can use `gsettings`.
To find schemas which store keymappings:

```
gsettings list-schemas |grep keybindings
  org.gnome.mutter.keybindings
  org.gnome.mutter.wayland.keybindings
  org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings
  org.gnome.shell.keybindings
```

They can be printed like this:

```
gsettings list-recursively org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings
  org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings cycle-windows-backward ['<Shift><Alt>Escape']
  org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings minimize ['<Super>h']
  org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings move-to-workspace-7 @as []
  (..)
```

On the target machine enter the output with `gsettings set ..` in front of every line:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings minimize "['<Super>h']"
```

Note that you need to put the value in quotes, or it will collide with shell substitutions.
Maybe something like this would be sufficient as transfer script for your keybindings:

```
gsettings list-recursively org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings |awk '{print "gsettings set "$1" "$2" \""$3"\""}'
```